# android studio asset studio not able to create image for Arabic image

Tags: android-studio, android-asset-studio

I need to create an image for  drawable-ar-xxxhdpi,drawable-ar-xxhdpi,
drawable-ar-xhdpi, drawable-ar-hdpi
How to do this in Asset Studio

Answer (score 0):

From Android studio -> Goto Configure->plugins. Search for "Batch Drawable importer" . Click Install. Then restart android studio.
Then goto drawable-> Right click then use Batch Drawable Importer